# Как переписать onPageScrolled с ViewPager на ViewPager2?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Я новичок в андроид разработке и мне нужно было сделать слайдер на viewpager2 с плавным изменением цвета во время свайпа. Я нашел решение здесь (решение №1): https://kubaspatny.github.io/2014/09/18/viewpager-background-transition/

Но у меня проблема, этот код написан под viewpager, а мне он нужен под viewpager2. пожалуйста, помогите с этим фрагментом кода, чтобы он работал с viewpager2:

```java
private class CustomOnPageChangeListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        mColorAnimation.setCurrentPlayTime((long)((positionOffset + position)* 10000000000l));
    }
}
```

Или, может быть, у вас есть другая статья о моей проблеме. буду очень благодарен за любую помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы переписать этот код с ViewPager на ViewPager2, воспользуйтесь абстрактным классом [`ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback):

```java
private class CustomOnPageChangeListener extends ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        // ваш код
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, помогло